# BFG Repo-Cleaner doesn't clean my gitlab repo

Tags: git, gitlab, git-rewrite-history

This is really worrying and stressful issue that I can't find any answer that works for me, so I cannot backup my code for over a year now (too bad!).

I am actually using [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage) to clean my repo. The actual total files size stands at few KB, but the remote size growth to about 9.8GB, making it impossible for me to `git push`.

Here's I did it:

```
repo-clean$ git clone --mirror https://gitlab.com/our-projects/my-specific-project.git
Cloning into bare repository 'my-specific-project.git'...
Username for 'https://gitlab.com': my-username
Password for 'https://my-username@gitlab.com': 
remote: Enumerating objects: 1306, done.
remote: Total 1306 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1306
Receiving objects: 100% (1306/1306), 9.73 GiB | 37.61 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (232/232), done.
```

Inspecting repo size:

```
repo-clean$ cd my-specific-project.git
repo-clean/my-specific-project.git$ du -sh *
4.0K    branches
4.0K    config
4.0K    description
4.0K    HEAD
64K hooks
8.0K    info
9.8G    objects
4.0K    packed-refs
12K refs

repo-clean/my-specific-project.git$ cd ..
repo-clean$
```

Then run BFG to clean my repo:

```
repo-clean$ java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 50M my-specific-project.git

Using repo : ~/repo-clean/my-specific-project.git

Scanning packfile for large blobs: 1306
Scanning packfile for large blobs completed in 172 ms.
Found 48 blob ids for large blobs - biggest=4510353716 smallest=74220532
Total size (unpacked)=25890690884
Found 132 objects to protect
Found 3 commit-pointing refs : HEAD, refs/heads/master, refs/merge-requests/1/head

Protected commits
-----------------

These are your protected commits, and so their contents will NOT be altered:

 * commit 628fb69b (protected by 'HEAD') - contains 3 dirty files : 
    - models/RF_modelGeolife.h5 (146.7 MB)
    - models/RF_modelSMF.h5 (249.3 MB)
    - models/RF_modelgeolife.h5 (146.7 MB)

WARNING: The dirty content above may be removed from other commits, but as
the *protected* commits still use it, it will STILL exist in your repository.

Details of protected dirty content have been recorded here :

~/repo-clean/my-specific-project.git.bfg-report/2022-05-09/15-50-17/protected-dirt/

If you *really* want this content gone, make a manual commit that removes it,
and then run the BFG on a fresh copy of your repo.
       

Cleaning
--------

Found 53 commits
Cleaning commits:       100% (53/53)
Cleaning commits completed in 150 ms.

Updating 2 Refs
---------------

    Ref                          Before     After   
    ------------------------------------------------
    refs/heads/master          | 628fb69b | 12113214
    refs/merge-requests/1/head | f1182758 | 6c3ad899

Updating references:    100% (2/2)
...Ref update completed in 30 ms.

Commit Tree-Dirt History
------------------------

    Earliest                                       Latest
    |                                                   |
    ..............DDDmmmDDDDmmmmDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDmmmmmmmmmm

    D = dirty commits (file tree fixed)
    m = modified commits (commit message or parents changed)
    . = clean commits (no changes to file tree)

                            Before     After   
    -------------------------------------------
    First modified commit | fc7cf2f9 | a772ae4a
    Last dirty commit     | d4a1a3d4 | c4a6ad7f

Deleted files
-------------

    Filename                                                    Git id                                                       
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3Class_Instances.pkl                                      | ceebb395 (558.1 MB)                                          
    Beijing_KerasData.pkl                                     | 8681a270 (133.4 MB)                                          
    Filtered_Trajectory.pkl                                   | bfe06d09 (137.8 MB)                                          
    Foot_Car_Instances.pkl                                    | c4bea045 (537.3 MB)                                          
    Foot_Car_Instances2.pkl                                   | 8d9b96ad (537.3 MB)                                          
    Instance_Geolife.pickle                                   | ee16e13b (412.5 MB)                                          
    Instance_Geolife_Beijing.pkl                              | c2cd394a (409.6 MB)                                          
    RF_modelGeolife.h5                                        | 5629ee4d (146.7 MB)                                          
    RF_modelSMF.h5                                            | 14372982 (249.3 MB)                                          
    RF_modelgeolife.h5                                        | 36293e2c (146.7 MB)                                          
    Revised_InstanceCreation+NoJerkOutlier+NOSmoothing.pickle | 29ff8dd4 (269.6 MB)                                          
    Revised_KerasData_NoSmoothing.pickle                      | 2421f835 (91.7 MB), 775b6041 (1.5 GB)                        
    Revised_Trajectory_Label_Array.pickle                     | 059a4596 (84.5 MB)                                           
    Revised_Trajectory_Label_Array2017.pickle                 | 7e24d6f7 (216.7 MB)                                          
    Revised_Trajectory_Label_Array2018.pickle                 | cee1e176 (791.3 MB)                                          
    ...


In total, 71 object ids were changed. Full details are logged here:

    ~/repo-clean/my-specific-project.git.bfg-report/2022-05-09/15-50-17

BFG run is complete! When ready, run: git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Strip out the unwanted dirty data:

```
repo-clean$ cd my-specific-project.git
~/repo-clean/my-specific-project.git$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
Enumerating objects: 1310, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1310/1310), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1242/1242), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1310/1310), done.
Building bitmaps: 100% (53/53), done.
Total 1310 (delta 245), reused 962 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

Then tried pushing to remote, which should have been the last step, but failed :

```
~/repo-clean/my-specific-project.git$ git push
Username for 'https://gitlab.com': my-username
Password for 'https://my-username@gitlab.com': 
Enumerating objects: 1310, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1310/1310), 2.08 GiB | 21.02 MiB/s, done.
Total 1310 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1310
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (245/245), done.
remote: GitLab: Your push to this repository has been rejected because it would exceed storage limits. Please contact your GitLab administrator for more information.
To https://gitlab.com/our-projects/my-specific-project.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] refs/merge-requests/1/head -> refs/merge-requests/1/head (deny updating a hidden ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://our-projects/my-specific-project.git'
```

It seems BFG has reduced the repo size to about 2.1GB (this includes untrack `dir` such as `venv` and data `dir`).

```
~/repo-clean/my-specific-project.git$ du -sh *
4.0K    branches
4.0K    config
4.0K    description
4.0K    HEAD
64K hooks
12K info
2.1G    objects
4.0K    packed-refs
16K refs
```

**Note**

I have also used similar tools such as [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html) but generated error that I [reported](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/error-rpc-failed-http-524-curl-22-the-requested-url-returned-error-524/65864) to GitLab community but didn't receive any help, as well as `gitlab-rake` described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/cleanup.html#remove-unreferenced-lfs-files-from-filesystem) but to no success.

Comment: Did you do what the `warning` suggests? If you don't, those three big files will still be present.

Comment: Ah, I have seen the `warning` but I am not sure what the suggestion `If you *really* want this content gone, make a manual commit that removes it` means. Manual commit...???

Comment: It presumably means you delete those three files (from the index at the very least) and commit. Note that you would then need to run BFG _again_ as explained by the warning text.

Comment: I would recommend following the [documented procedure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html) for reducing the repository size. This is the _only_ way to effectively reduce the repository size in the case of using GitLab because of how GitLab holds onto refs. Not sure about the 524 error you're getting, though.

Answer (score 4):

Note the `warning`. This is telling you that three very large files are in your *most recent commit*, also known as `HEAD`. BFG cannot remove those.

As the `warning` tells you, you should `git rm --cached` those three files (and any other unwanted large files, while you are at it) and then `git commit`, and then run BFG *again* in order to fix the problem.

(Be sure to add all those files to your `.gitignore` too, of course, so they don't accidentally get added to a commit ever again.)